# Bootstrap Typeahead in Dropdown No Background

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-typeahead

My Bootstrap typeahead seems to have no background menu.  Does anybody know a fix?

**EDIT:** the issue is that the 'dropup' class is being applied to my typeahead.  How can I ignore that class in the scope of my typeahead?

The markup is as follows:

```
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropup" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li>
                                    <input type="text" class="typeahead" data-provide="typeahead" autocomplete="off">
                                </li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li role="presentation">
                                    <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button">
                                        Close
                                    </button>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: No special CSS besides the included Bootstrap CSS

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be wrapped around a `<div class="dropdown">`